# selected option laravel livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a dropdown and in edit page I want to show old input. I use this code but it still shows "please select". Where is the problem?

```php
<select wire:model.defer="form.department" id="form.department" class="tf-input">
    <option value="null" selected disabled>{{ __('Please select') }}</option>
    @foreach($this->departments as $department)
        <option {{ $form->department_id == $department->id ? 'selected' : '' }} value="{{ $department->id }}" >{{ $department->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: I tried this, not working

Answer (score 6):

Livewire does not listen to `selected` attributes in HTML when you are using `wire:model`, because it will overwrite it with the value from the component. Therefor, remove it entirely.

```html
<select wire:model.defer="form.department" id="form.department" class="tf-input">
    <option value="null" disabled>{{ __('Please select') }}</option>
    @foreach ($this->departments as $department)
        <option value="{{ $department->id }}" wire:key="department-{{ $department->id }}">{{ $department->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

As you can see, I removed the parts that adds `selected`, but I also added a `wire:key` to the options - this is because the elements are rendered in a loop, and will help Livewire keep track of all elements on a page.

To set a value that is bound through `wire:model`, you need to set the value in the component. So in the `mount()` method, you can do

```php
$this->form['department'] = $department->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use every attributes that you use in front to your mount. for example in bootstrap select like this without livewire we have this things:

```
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="attribute_ids">ویژگی</label>
                    <select id="attributeSelect" name="attribute_ids[]" class="form-control" multiple
                        data-live-search="true">
                        @foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
                            <option value="{{ $attribute->id }}"
                                {{ in_array($attribute->id , $category->attributes()->pluck('id')->toArray()) ? 'selected' : '' }}
                                >{{ $attribute->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="attribute_is_filter_ids">انتخاب ویژگی های قابل فیلتر</label>
                    <select id="attributeIsFilterSelect" name="attribute_is_filter_ids[]" class="form-control" size="3" multiple
                        data-live-search="true">
                        @foreach ($category->attributes()->wherePivot('is_filter', 1)->get() as $attribute)
                            <option value="{{ $attribute->id }}" selected>{{ $attribute->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label for="attribute_is_filter_ids">انتخاب ویژگی متغیر</label>
                    <select id="variationSelect" name="variation_id" class="form-control" multiple size="3" data-live-search="true">
                        <option value="{{ $category->attributes()->wherePivot('is_variation', 1)->first()->id }}" selected>{{ $category->attributes()->wherePivot('is_variation', 1)->first()->name }}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

but with livewire we have this code:

```
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3" wire:ignore>
                    <label for="attribute_ids">ویژگی</label>
                    <select id="attributeSelect" wire:model="attribute_ids" class="form-control" multiple
                        data-live-search="true">
                        @foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
                            <option value="{{ $attribute->id }}"
                                >{{ $attribute->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    @error('attribute_ids') <div class="mt-1"><span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span></div> @enderror

                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-3" wire:ignore>
                    <label for="attribute_is_filter_ids">انتخاب ویژگی های قابل فیلتر</label>
                    <select id="attributeIsFilterSelect" wire:model="attribute_is_filter_ids" class="form-control" size="3" multiple
                        data-live-search="true">
                        @foreach ($category->attributes()->wherePivot('is_filter', 1)->get() as $attribute)
                            <option value="{{ $attribute->id }}">{{ $attribute->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    @error('attribute_is_filter_ids') <div class="mt-1"><span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span></div> @enderror

                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-3" wire:ignore>
                    <label for="attribute_is_filter_ids">انتخاب ویژگی متغیر</label>
                    <select id="variationSelect" wire:model="variation_id" class="form-control" multiple size="3" data-live-search="true">
                        <option value="{{ $category->attributes()->wherePivot('is_variation', 1)->first()->id }}" >{{ $category->attributes()->wherePivot('is_variation', 1)->first()->name }}</option>
                    </select>
                    @error('variation_id') <div class="mt-1"><span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span></div> @enderror

                </div>
```

and in mount he have:

```
    public function mount($id) {

    $this->category = Category::find($id);
    $this->attribute_ids = $this->category->attributes()->pluck('id')->toArray();
    $this->attribute_is_filter_ids = $this->category->attributes()->wherePivot('is_filter', 1)->pluck('id')->toArray();
    $this->variation_id = $this->category->attributes()->wherePivot('is_variation', 1)->first()->id;

}
```